# Integer.MAX_VALUE in Spring application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Do we have something like `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to specify in the `application.properties`? We can do something similar using `@ConfigurationProperties`, but I was looking for an option in Spring `application.properties`.

Comment: `application.properties` doesn't support SpEL expressions, which would've been able to resolve `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to its actual value. I think the best you'll be able to do is define a custom property source that sources the constants you want, then reference them in `application.properties`. At that point, it seems more worthwhile to just keep the defaults in Java.

Comment: You could use `Integer.MAX` as default value for the specific property. This way you would only need to declare a value in your `application.properties` if a specific one is needed. (Where in this context I look at `Integer.MAX` as unspecific )

Comment: Please, did you find any solution for this?